# Permissions of Samba share bind mount in SFTP jailed directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, samba, sftp

I run a SFTP and Samba server on the same machine. In order to access the SFTP more conveniently in the local network it should be also accessible from there. For this I bind mounted it into an existing Samba share (`sudo mount --bind /home/sftp_user/share/ /path/to/samba/share/sftp-share/`).

I jailed the SFTP directory like this:

```bsh
sudo chown root:root /home/sftp_user
sudo chmod 0755 /home/sftp_user

sudo mkdir /home/sftp_user/share
sudo chown root:sftponly /home/sftp_user/share
sudo chmod 0755 /home/sftp_user/share
```

Some restrictions:

- I cannot add the Samba user to the `sftponly` group since `ssh` would not work anymore (the user has both `ssh` and Samba access)
- SFTP auth works with key files; `ssh` auth with 2fa(password + OTP) -> this authentication methods should stay like this
- Changing the owner of `share` to the Samba user works partly: I can add files via SFTP and Samba but the SFTP user can (obviously) not delete files from the Samba user

  ```
    sudo chown samba_user:sftponly /home/sftp_user/share
  ```

The only option which seem to work is setting the permissions quite broad:

```bsh
sudo chown root:sftponly /home/sftp_user/share        # Stays the same
sudo chmod 0777 /home/sftp_user/share
```

This raises some security concerns.

In general for every user it would be O.K. to access (read and write) `/home/sftp_user/share` (via Samba or SFTP). Is the working example the way to go or are there better (secure, but not too complicated) solutions to this (ACLs are probably an option but I think this would be an overkill in this case).

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: `VERSION="18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"`

Comment: Meanwhile I am on version 22.04; still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

FYI i just ran into a case where Samba suddenly stopped authenticating my user when using a bind mount instead of a normal mount. since this is a legacy nightmare i am also on 18.04.x -  it could be an issue with bind mounts.